# How to automatically reindex sunspot when database changed on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I learn the Sunspot_rails project today,

refer to my demo clip : http://youtu.be/qmtbDg4VtOw

and  whenever add an new item into database,

we should do

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```

so that we can search the new added date via sunspot search.

is there better way to

> automatically

run

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```

when the database changed?

thanks in advance

PS: if run the rake sunspot:reindex in command line, it will show the confirm prompt.Can I disable the option.
    [books] $ rake sunspot:reindex

```
*Note: the reindex task will remove your current indexes and start from scratch.
If you have a large dataset, reindexing can take a very long time, possibly weeks.
This is not encouraged if you have anywhere near or over 1 million rows.
Are you sure you want to drop your indexes and completely reindex? (y/n)


# Sunspot
  searchable do
    text  :name
    text  :author
    text  :comment
    text  :sale_type
    text  :category
    # text  :isbn
  end
```

sunspot.yml

```
[config] $ cat sunspot.yml
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
```

Comment: By default new data should be added to index in `save` callback added by Sunspot (just as @MauricioLinhares wrote), if you receive different behaviour paste your `searchable` block.

Comment: Do you have `auto_commit_after_request: false` line in your `config/sunspot.yml` file added to your environment? Edit: and about silencing boolean prompt: try `rake sunspot:reindex[,,true]` this **should** perform reindex without asking you for confirmation, but this depends on your `sunspot_solr` gem version (or you can just overwrite that specific task).

Comment: I don't have auto_commit_after_request in the sunspot.yml

Answer (score 0):

By default, `sunspot` you update your model on `Solr` whenever you save it to the database, you don't have to manually reindex any models.

The `rake sunspot:reindex` command should only be run when you change the fields indexed by your model or when you change your `schema.xml` file on `Solr`.

Comment: Oops, I hope so, but in my case, you are wrong. I have to re-index so that new added data can be searched. I attach the 20sec clip to show.